# GetItem from Secondary Index with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm just getting started using DynamoDB and have setup an 'accounts' table.

I've set-up a secondary index so I can query an api user and user key.
Neither of these values are the primary key, as they are both volatile and can be changed.

The Table is built with

```
TableName: "Accounts",
        KeySchema:  [
            { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH" },
            { AttributeName: "email", KeyType: "RANGE" }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions: [
            { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "S" },
            { AttributeName: "email", AttributeType: "S" }
        ]
```

And the Index is

```
 TableName: 'Accounts',
            AttributeDefinitions: [
                {AttributeName: 'name', AttributeType: 'S'},
                {AttributeName: 'apiKey', AttributeType: 'S'}
            ],
            GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates: [
                {
                    Create: {
                        IndexName: "ApiAccounts",
                        ProvisionedThroughput: {
                            ReadCapacityUnits: 1, WriteCapacityUnits: 1
                        },
                        KeySchema: [
                            {AttributeName: 'name', KeyType: "HASH"},
                            {AttributeName: 'apiKey', KeyType: "STRING"} 
                        ],
                        Projection: {
                            ProjectionType: "KEYS_ONLY"
                        },
```

I'm now trying to get a uses account by querying the `ApiAccounts` index.

I'm trying

```
 dynamoClient.get({
            TableName: 'Accounts',
            IndexName: 'ApiAccounts',
            Key: {
                name: nameKeyArray[0],
                apiKey: nameKeyArray[1]
            }, callback)
```

But I am getting an error `One of the required keys was not given a value`, which leads me to believe I can't do a 'get' on a Index? Or I'm not referring the index properly. Can somebody clarify for me?

Name and API Key are unique, so I think I want to avoid a query or scan if possible

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I guess its not so clear from the official docs. You may perform `Scan` or `Query` operation on `GSI` index, but not the `GetItem` operation.

For every record / item in a `Table`, they must have unique `HASH` and `RANGE` keys.

i.e.

```
// assume dummy api putItem(id, email, name, apiKey)
account.putItem("1", "abc@email.com", "john", "key1") // OK
account.putItem("1", "abc@email.com", "john", "key1") // NOT OK, id and email are table HASH and RANGE keys, must be unique
```

But for `Index`'es, `Hash` and `Range` keys are not unique, they may contain duplicated records / items.

i.e.

```
// assume dummy api putItem(id, email, name, apiKey)
account.putItem("1", "abc@email.com", "john", "key1") // OK
account.putItem("1", "bcd@email.com", "john", "key1") // OK
```

i.e.

```
// assume dummy api putItem(id, email, name, apiKey)
account.putItem("1", "abc@email.com", "john", "key1") // OK
account.putItem("2", "abc@email.com", "john", "key1") // OK
```

**Java**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Index.html

`Index` implements `QueryApi` and `ScanApi` but not `GetItemApi`.

**JavaScript**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property

`GetItem` does **not** accept `IndexName` as a parameter.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property

`Query` accepts `IndexName` as a parameter.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property

`Scan` accepts `IndexName` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was all over http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JavaScript.html - I'm assuming Query would be best for my use case and performance?

Comment: @pedalpete yes, however be mindful that there can be duplicate records returned when you are querying an Index because an Index's Hash and Range keys are not unique, unlike a Table.