# AWS Dynamodb ..NET Core LoadAsync doesnt use secondary key as search key

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, facebook-sdk-4.0

we are using DynamoDb  with .net core and Implementing facebook login. Normally, we use uuid as userid in db but  with facebook login, I want to save facebook user id as secondary key  to be able to Load items using facebook id.

When user login with facebook, I set  FacebookToken field of user as regular fields.However, I'm not able to Load user using that index..

```
return await _context.LoadAsync<DbDynamoUser>(playerId,new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "FacebookToken" });
```

DynamoDbTable

```
[DynamoDBTable("Users")]

public class DbDynamoUser 
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    

    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey]
    public string FacebookToken { get; set; }


    [DynamoDBProperty(typeof(DynamoDbUserConverter))]
    public LocalUser User { get; set; }

    public UserLogs Logs { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationMethod { get; set; }
    public string LastDeviceUuid { get; set; }
}
```

Even if I specify IndexName, LoadAsync uses primary key as search key.

[Dynamodb index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsMlc.png)

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled into the same issue. I couldn't figure out why `LoadAsync` wasn't using my global secondary index. I kept getting a `InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Guid'.` (My Id property is configured as a Guid type).

After hunting around, I came across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43733229 which pointed me in the right direction.

As explained in that answer, you may perform Scan or Query operation on GSI index but not the GetItem (LoadAsync in our case) operation.

For every item in a table, they must have unique Hash and Range keys but for GSI, Hash and Range keys are not unique, they may contain duplicated items.

Switching from `LoadAsync`:

```
return await _context.LoadAsync<User>(emailAddress);
```

To `QueryAsync` then resolved my issue:

```
var search = _context.QueryAsync<User>(emailAddress, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = nameof(User.EmailAddress) });
var firstSet = await search.GetNextSetAsync();

if (firstSet.Count > 1)
    throw new Exception($"Duplicate email address found \"{emailAddress}\"");
if (firstSet.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception($"User with email address \"{emailAddress}\" was not found");

return firstSet[0];
```